# Can you update a fedora/centos/redhat system via a kickstart file?

Tags: centos, upgrade, live-usb, kickstart

I have an existing CentOS installation.  I want to know if I can update the system by booting with a kickstart file.

Even better, I would like to create some install media that would boot a system and perform updates on the system.  Perhaps create a live ISO file from the kickstart file, boot the live ISO and perform the update.

Anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Do you mean update from 7 to 8?

Comment: No, I want to update custom packages from a custom live iso or a Kickstart file.